# Does having a companion onboard give away your position?

Tags: firefly

The Serenity is regularly involved in activities of dubious legality, and is often on the run from either the authorities or powerful criminals and mobsters.

In the meanwhile, Inara, a companion, travels with them, communicates regularly with her guild, asks them information on potential clients on the planets they visit and arranges trades with them.

So it seems to me that someone powerful enough (or connected enough, or with enough hacking abilities) could infer the position of the spaceship by monitoring her activity. Isn't this a problem? Why does no one worries about the fact that their "ambassador" might make their position known to their enemies?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Until the events of the film, the crew of the cargo ship Serenity aren't really trying to hide from anyone in particular. They regularly submit to custom inspection, register their presence on the [Cortex](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Cortex) and bid for cargo shuttling work (even including Alliance work on one occasion). All of this suggests that they have no major problem with people knowing their location.

Under the surface, obviously they're supplementing their incomes through smuggling, bank robbery and various nefarious activities but the trick is that they need to ***look*** legitimate. Having a registered companion on board gives them an excuse to travel to places and planets that would frown on the arrival of a jobbing cargo ship.

> **Inara:**  *Yes, because I can bring something that your surveyor or any of the other fish you might have on line can't.  A certain respectability.*
>
> **Mal:**  *Respectability?*
>
> **Inara:** *And based on what little I've seen of your "operation," I suspect that's something you could use.*
>
> **Mal:**  *Fine.  Let me ask you this:  if you're so respectable, why are you even here?  I mean, I've heard tell of fancy ladies such as yourself shipping out with big luxury liners, and the like.  But a registered companion on a boat like this?  What are you running from?*